# This Environment was initialized without a V8::Inspector

Tags: node.js, electron

Strange error when trying to parse and understand some code using Node's Inspector API with electron.  Not really sure how to use it, but I keep getting this error.  I wonder if somehow I have to start it with the debugger enabled?  The thing is I want to use this in production so I'd rather not have to enable the debugger.  Any ideas?

```
import * as inspectorRaw from 'node:inspector';
import { promisifyAll } from 'bluebird';
const inspector = promisifyAll(inspectorRaw);

async function main() {
    const session = new inspector.Session();
    session.connect();
    let result = await session.post('Runtime.compileScript', { expression: "console.log('test')", sourceURL: './test.js', persistScript: true });
    result = await session.post('Runtime.globalLexicalScopeNames',{})
}
main()
```

Produces this error:

```
This Environment was initialized without a V8::Inspector
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out.  It's because this was in the `preload` section and was running in the browser, so the API wasn't available.